# Изменить размеры изображения или удлинить ее по вертикали без потери качества

Tags: java, spring, itext

У меня есть таблица созданая в iText которая выглядит следующим образом.

[image: Штрих-код при нормальной высоте ячейки]

[image: Штрих-код при высоте больше чем 60%]

** Таблицы на обе картинки имеют одинковый размер*

Высота каждой ячейки является динамической(сам задаю) и в сумме должно составлять 100%. Таким образом, если я установлю значение первой ячейки на 60% от общей высоты ячеек, то я хочу, чтобы штрих-код автоматически удлинялся по вертикали. Я с трудом нахожу, как это сделать в iText, и поэтому ищу, как задавать размеры при генерации. Но в библиотека которая я ипспользую категорически отказывается устанавливать нестандартные размеры. Если я указываю "неправильные" размеры, то один из них(высота или ширина) игнорируется чтобы картика небыла неравномерной.

```
    public String generateBarcode(final String barcodeText) {
    final var barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(barcodeText);
    final var bufferedImage = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);

    final var tempFile = File.createTempFile("barcode", ".png");
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", tempFile);
    return tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

И вот вопрос, может есть способ удлинить штрих код изображения при генерации или в iText.
Было бы отлично если есть что-то чтобы удлинить по вертикали.

**Спасибо за ответ Михаилу Реброву и Труфальдино:**

```
final var imageCell = new PdfPCell();
final var barcodeImage = generateBarcode("Text", settings)
final var image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(barcodeImage, Color.BLACK, true);
    
imageCell.setImage(image);

***********************************
    
public java.awt.Image generateBarcode(final String barcodeText, final ProductTagSettingsDTO settings) {
final var barcodeHeight = settings.getTagHeight().floatValue() / 100 * settings.getFirstRowHeightPercentage();
    
final var barcode128 = new Barcode128();
barcode128.setCode(barcodeText);
barcode128.setBarHeight(barcodeHeight);
barcode128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
return barcode128.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: на этот раз не такой подробный, но если будут вопросы, правки или возражения - пиши комментарии под ответом

Comment: Itext какой версии  вы используете для  генерации штрих кода?  Учитывая, что теперь itext   меняется очень быстро,  важна версия .

Comment: @Труфальдино Это точно не iText. по сигнатурам методов я нашел только `Barbeсue` какое-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try(PdfWriter writer =  new  PdfWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);
                   PdfDocument pdfD = new PdfDocument(writer);
                   Document doc = new Document(pdfD))
                   {
      doc.add(new Paragraph( "Test Barcode"));
      Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128(pdfD);
      code128.setGenerateChecksum(true);
      code128.setCode("Truffaldino  from  bergamo" + " code128.setBarHeight(128)" );
      code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
      code128.setBarHeight(128);
      PdfFormXObject xObject =  code128.createFormXObject(ColorConstants.RED, ColorConstants.BLACK,pdfD);
      doc.add( new Image(xObject));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
используя метод setBarHeight можно меть размер barcodes (мы говорим о 128)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ответ очень помог

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, можно просто масштабировать данное изображение.
Но тут без потерь качества не обойтись. Правда я не думаю что на штрихкоде это как-то заметно отобразится

Вот вспомогательный метод для масштабирования изображения

```
BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) throws IOException {
    Image resultingImage = originalImage.getScaledInstance(targetWidth, targetHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    outputImage.getGraphics().drawImage(resultingImage, 0, 0, null);
    return outputImage;
}
```

И потом уже можно будет по месту указывать какого именно размера должен быть штрихкод

```
final var bufferedImage = resizeImage(BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode), width, height);
```

В противном случае можно попробовать сразу генерировать изображение в нужном размере.
Но для этого нужно знать возможно ли это в принципе. Для чего в свою очередь нужно знать каким именно инструментом для генерации штрихкода ты пользуешься.

Comment: т.е Вы генерируете  barcode, затем делаете его изображениеми добавлете в pdf,  где теряется масштабирование?  Вы  bufferedImage для чего создаете?  Вы его куда  возвращаете ?

Comment: @Труфальдино, я его не генерирую. Чем и как оно генерируется неизвестно. Известно что в результате сего действа возвращается BufferedImage о котором вы и спрашивали.

Comment: @Труфальдино, и если вы не заметили, то в ответе я сам рекомендовал сразу генерировать штрихкод нужного размера, поэтому не очень понимаю суть ваших претензий

Comment: Михаил у меня нет к Вам ни одной претензии! Я сожалею,что вам показалось ,что у меня к Вам претензии.  В таком случае  предлагаю  идти  по  вашему пути и  менять  масштаб в  самом  itext

Comment: @Труфальдино, работаем с тем, что есть. У данного автора под другими вопросами я уже несколько раз пытался выяснить детали (и все безуспешно). Хотя вопросы он отмечает. Поэтому выяснить детали на этот раз я даже не пытался. Вы можете написать свой ответ. Я к примеру не знал что iText может генерерировать штрихкод.  Можете предложить свой вариант с их использованием. Я вам даже плюсик за это поставлю.

Comment: https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.2.0/com/itextpdf/barcodes/Barcode128.html -это  докуммментация. itext генерирует barcode давно и успешно.  А вполседни х версиях  можно даже  цвета менять и  поддерживаются фонты кастомные

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я уверен что и этот метод подходит, но у Труфальдино более простой.